# do we have any action to import entire sheet in blue prism?

Tags: excel, excel-automation, blueprism

> Do we need to create 1000 fields in our collection, if we have
>   thousand column in our excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

No.If you do not define any fields within the Collection you are importing the data to, Blue Prism will dynamically populate the fields with the values in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to define these fields - once you import the worksheet into collection, then the fields will be automatically imported form first row.